# How do I conditionally change column colors in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau, I have a column indicating positive or negative profit. If it's above 0 -- I want the column color green, If it's below 0, I want the column color red.

Answer (score 2):

1. Drag Measure Values to Colour

   2. Click the colour filter card and choose 'Edit colours'
   3. Choose the colour theme you'd like (in your case, red/green diverging), tick 'stepped colour' and set to '2' steps.
   4. Click 'Advanced' and set your 'Center' to '0'.

This will apply to the whole chart, if you want to apply this to one column only, you need to right click on the colour 'Measure Values' pill and select 'Use Separate Legends'.

Comment: Great. When I try doing this, though, it won't let me return the values to the Row/column area without both columns I need reverting back to blue.

Comment: Hi - you'll need to split to separate legends so you can format only the one you want, and set the second to a solid colour of your preference.

Comment: What if there are 3 colors viz Green (0-10%), Amber (10-15%) and Red (>15%)? I don't see an option to pick the specific 3 colors even though under stepped colour, 3-steps are available

Answer (score 0):

1.First create a new calculated field say "Profit/Loss" and set the condition something like:

---

IF ([Profit]))< 0 THEN "Loss"
ELSE "Profit" END

---

2. Keep the Datatype as 'string' and convert this to Dimension.
3. Now drag your "Profit/Loss" field to "color" option on the Marks card and then edit the colors as per your requirement.

*Later on you can hide this column from you visualization.